# How to import `isOneline` function?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I need to create a custom matcher for Jest test framework, specifically same as `.toEqual()` but with optional `message` parameter.

I started with copying everything from actual `.toEqual()` matcher [from here](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/cb87c0a8536519a3ad2f89cfe357a0d2ae99d22c/packages/expect/src/matchers.js#L365).

I managed to bring all of the the used in this matcher functions except `isOneline`. It is [defined here](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/cb87c0a8536519a3ad2f89cfe357a0d2ae99d22c/packages/expect/src/utils.js#L254).

But I do not see how can I import/require it to my code. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
const { isOneline} = require('<path to util.js file>');
```

Or

```
const isOneline= require('<path to util.js file>').isOneline;
```

**EDIT:**

This works (see comment):

```
const isOneline = require('expect/build/utils').isOneline;
```

Comment: Yes, i tried `const isOneline = require('expect/utils');` and `const { isOneline } = require('expect/utils');` but got `Cannot find module 'expect/utils' from 'matchers.ts'`